# Windows Security prompt after page load?

Tags: login, ie

I have a SharePoint 2013 site and users keep getting a login prompt after the page finishes loading. they only get the error in IE in Chrome and FireFox they don't get the error. And in IE the error goes away if you turn on the developer tools.

The prompt is always after the page has already loaded. I thought it could be an image that is trying to load from a document library that no one has access to. Is there any way to see the url of the resource that caused the login prompt? Or does anyone have any idea what could be causing the login prompt?

Answer (score 2):

Download [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) and see from what resource the access denied error comes from.

Comment: I have tried this now as well and I get the same problem as when I turn off the IE debugging tools. That I am not getting the error while Fiddler is running. I also tried loading the page while running procmon. I do get the error then but procmon doesn't get the details the details that I need to see what on the page is causing the error.

Comment: Do you have some browser Add-Ons that might be causing this?